# new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple error callng floodfill

Tags: python, tuples, python-imaging-library, argument-unpacking

I am not sure what is going on.
This thing worked before and now it dosn't.

```
def generate_unity_texture(self, monKey_data):

    width, height = self.texture_image.size
    eye_position = (int(0.88 * width), int(0.88 * height))
    ImageDraw.floodfill(unity_texture_copy, xy=eye_position , value=monKey_data['eye_color'])

return unity_texture_copy
```

and I get `SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple`.
The problem is in `pixel[x, y] = value` and it is mentioned that the problamatic line of code is PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 349, in floodfill

This is a tuple. I even tried to replace middle with `(int(middle[0]), int(middle[1])` but got the same result.
In the documentation `xy` is:

> xy – Seed position (a 2-item coordinate tuple).

Which is exactly what I did.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 'This thing worked before'  Before what ?

Comment: Is this your real code? Because it's indented strangely, and your last line has one left parenthesis and two right parentheses. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Edited it to my real code. And before means I worked on it a month ago, and now I updated every decency, maybe PILLOW made a weird update that massed this up?

Comment: The [pillow docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill) have a warning for this method that says "This method is experimental", so maybe it's a bug. Check and make sure you've to the latest version of the library.